# Javascript navigation causes bugs in pages

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an application that allows a user to input information to request a transfer to be booked from the arriving airport. If the user already has a booking requested, on page load, a `Bootstrap` modal appears and states that they have information already present in the system, and to confirm that they would like to change the information. If they cancel, they are returned to the previous page using the `history.back()` function in Javascript.

However, if the user presses forward on their browser after being brought to the first page, and returns to the booking request form, it will not show the modal as intended and allows them to edit their original booking without showing the modal for confirmation. Is there a way around this bug?

I am executing the modal using this following function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#booking_modal').modal({
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: true
    });
    $('#booking_modal button#cancel').on('click', function() {
      window.location.href = '/arrivals';
    });
}).call(this);
```

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are executing the modal?

Comment: That is probably not a bug.